# Can I use where in eloquent while giving it an object?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel & Eloquent, I'm coming from Django.

In Django I can create a filter on my results and use an object to filter the results...

I'm trying to figure out if I could do this in Laravel/Eloquent also...

Here's what I'm trying to do....

create_messages_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMessagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('message');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('messages');
    }
}
```

Message.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

MessageController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $messages = Message::where("user", Auth::user())->get();

        dd($messages);
        return $messages;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the controller index() function is routed too... I get an error saying "user" column does not exist... and it doesn't but I assumed the models user() function would take care of that and that I would be able to compare it's returning object with Auth::user().

Am I wrong, or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the "where" query, the first parameter must be a column in the database. If you want to make use of a "user" column, I'll suggest you add a user column to your table. 
I think the auth:user() is to authenticate the current user. 
So laravel eloquent is only alerting you that the "user" column does not exist.  I will suggest you create a user column, and see what happens next.

Comment: I understand that, what I'm trying to ask is if it's possible to preform a query using an object (User object) since user_id is the id of a user... I assumed through relations it would be possible...